# Preventing repeated periods in citations

Tags: bibtex, punctuation

I'm using natbib to do citations in text, and sometimes those citations end with a period. When this corresponds to the end of a sentence, a duplicate period can easily be inserted. A MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\begin{document}

I want to cite \cite{Doe14}, but if I put the citation at the end of a sentence, I get an extra period, as in \citeauthor{Doe14}.

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem[{{Doe et~al.}(2014)}]{Doe14}
{Doe}, J. and collaborators 2014, Nature, 123, 321
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Now I could of course just remove the period from the end of the sentence, but every time I re-read it, I think I'm missing a period and re-add it.  Is it possible to create an "optional" punctuation, which is present only if the preceeding character is not the same punctuation?

Comment: Really, what is needed is an "optional" punctuation which is present only if the _subsequent_ character is not the same. Then it could be put in the bibitem, and useage in the text would not change.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be entering the bibliography "by hand" (unless you have done that simply to create your MWE, which of course (since you've tagged your question `bibtex` is possible).

Anyway, much as I hate answering a question with "use some bibliography package you are not using", I'm going to stick my neck out and say that this makes a good case for using `biblatex`, which does exactly what you have in mind. No doubt that shows that, if you wanted to, you could recreate it yourself; but the code is pretty complex, to say the least: have a look at `biblatex2.sty` if you have a few days spare to tinker. One of the (many) useful things about `biblatex` is its intelligence about punctuation in just this sort of situation.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Doe14,
  author = "Doe, J. and others",
  title  = "Title",
  journaltitle = "Nature",
  volume = {123},
  pages = {321},
  date = {2014},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[natbib,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}

I want to cite \cite{Doe14}, and if I put the citation at the end of a sentence, 
I \emph{don't} get an extra period, as in \citeauthor{Doe14}. As you can see, 
we get only one full stop. But we still get it if we don't add the period 
ourselves: \citeauthor{Doe14} (which is correct: because the dot at the end 
of ``et al.'') is there because it's an abbreviation).


\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This produces the following:

[image: output image]

Now of course the actual bibliographical output here is different from that in your case (it is the "standard" `biblatex` style `authoryear`); but there are other author/year styles available, if you don't like that. Have a look at the APA style and the chicago style with the `authordate` option, in particular: they are very stable author/year styles.

**APA**

[image: APA style output]

**Chicago** (`authordate`) (gives "Doe et al. 2014" in text)

[image: Chicago authordate style]

(I've added the `natbib` option to `biblatex` here because you were using `natbib`, but in fact it's unnecessary and probably not recommended: `biblatex` has its own set of commands. And as you can see the `natbib` option only produces a superficial similarity of interface: the actual output is controlled by `biblatex`.)