# Using "\citeauthor{key}." at the end of a phrase renders repeated points

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib, punctuation

The present question is a follow-up question to this one: [Preventing repeated periods in citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171977/preventing-repeated-periods-in-citations/171993#171993)

I have the same problem, using `\citeauthor{key}.` at the end of a phrase for a reference with more than 2 authors renders two points in the document, due to the *et al.* abbreviation. I use the `natbib` package, and my bibliography style is provided by my university. In the linked question, the answer was to use `biblatex` but I can't do that, at least not right now. I want to know if there is any function that I could add into my university's `.bst` file that could get rid of the extra point shown in the MWE. Something able to recognize that I'm putting the point manually after the \citeauthor{key} and ignores the point after the *et al.* inside the text.

Has anybody seen this type of function in a `.bst` file? Could you point out in an example?

Thanks as usually.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\begin{document}


This is a citation to \cite{Doe14}, but if I put the citation at the end of a sentence, I get an extra period, as in \citeauthor{Doe14}.


\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem[{{Doe et~al.}(2014)}]{Doe14}
{Doe}, J. and collaborators 2014, Nature, 123, 321
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you even using a `.bst`? You appear to be creating your bibliography manually using `thebibliography`. Regarding the full stops: I would just use a `sed` script at the end to eliminate my errors in the final version.

Comment: @cfr Yes, I'm using a ``.bst`` file and I have a ``.bbl`` library, but did not put it them the MWE. Seemed easier. It's like in journal articles: you have a ``.bbl`` library, and then you have to copy at the end of your ``.tex`` document the content of the ``.bib`` generated by ``bibtex`` using the journal's ``.bst`` format. Sorry if it was misleading. From which file would you eliminate the double points using ``sed``? Thanks BTW

Comment: @cfr That's the thing. If I eliminate all the points after the ``\citeautho{}`` it will be incorrect. And it will depend if the article or book has more than two authors, so they will compressed as an *et al.* statement. Formatting manually. Paying attention to the format. Writing the document thinking in the output. Those are not normally stuff related with LaTeX.

Comment: How often are you ending your sentences with `et al.`?  And why not reword them?  Otherwise, you're going to have to create a new command that is either super-clever (because it can peek ahead) or an "et al."-specific command that you'll only want to use when the citation will print `et al.` and end a sentence -- which sounds tedious. Easier just to remember: try not to end sentences with a reference to (the) author(s).  As far as I remember, I don't think I've ever ended a sentence that way and I was never even consciously trying to avoid it....

Comment: I've deleted that suggestion. I wasn't really understanding the question. I agree with @jon, I think. Do you really end sentences this way at all often? Although it probably depends on language. I'm thinking English, but in other languages, order varies. It is probably more likely in Welsh, though I'd be surprised if it was common. Maybe in other languages it is inevitable?

Comment: Have you see [xpunctuate](http://ctan.org/pkg/xpunctuate)?

Comment: No, but seems interesting. I guess I could define a macro that puts automatically a``\xperiod``. Something like ``\newcommand[1]{\citeauthorend}{\citeauthor{#1}\xperiod}`` EDIT: No that won't do it. Redefine ``\citeauthor`` directly is a better option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as @jon said in the comment, this is a grammatical problem. Maybe I'm using the *passive voice* too much. The easy solution is avoiding those `\citeauthor{key}` at the end of a phrase.

The technical solution uses `biblatex`, as recommended in the post linked in OP (here again as a reference: [Preventing repeated periods in citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171977/preventing-repeated-periods-in-citations/171993#171993)).

I'm adding this as an answer, so it shows in future searches, but I'm not sure if that is correct. My apologies if I'm wrong.

Thanks to all the users for their comments.

Comment: The passive voice is not uncommon in formal academic writing. I still struggle to think of a case in which I'd end a sentence with `\citeauthor`.

Comment: It is common to end phrases with ``\cite``, or even ``\citep``. There are certain cases where the reference was already mentioned in that paragraph, and adding the full ``\cite`` including the year would be repetitive.

Comment: Yes. I use citation commands at the end of sentences all the time. But not `\citeauthor`. And if you use e.g. `\citep{}` then you still need a full-stop afterwards. I commonly would have something like `... \citeauthor{}... \autocite*{}.` (I use Biblatex.) But I've never written `... \citeyear{}... \citeauthor{}.` That I can recall. I can't think of a use case.

Comment: What about: "``\cite{authorA}`` did something cool with lasers and stuff, while ``\cite{authorB}`` attempted to do something a bit less cool and without lasers, being unable to reproduce the results of ``\citeauthor{authorA}``." Not the most elegant stuff in the world, but quite frequent in academia (except for the cool part with lasers. That's not so common)

Comment: OK. I admit that is a possible use case. There isn't really any reason to use it (why not `X's results` rather than `the results of X`) but somebody might, indeed, do so.